# Simple minimax in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimax

I want to solve the basic optimisation problem for `max (min(ki.xi))` where `ki`'s are known constants and `x1+X2+......+x20=1`.
I've written the following code but I get different answers for different initial values of `X` taken. I think I'm getting stuck at local `Maxima`'s. Is there any way to fix this.

```
M=[9.3 5.3 4.4 4.4 1.7 4.8 4.8 11 1.7 5.2 8.1 6.2 2.8 3.2 4 3.9 4.6 1 2.5 7.6]*10^7;

N=[2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2/3 0.5 2 2 2 0.4 0.5 2];

x0=zeros(1,20);

lb=zeros(1,20);

ub=ones(1,20);

[a,b,Aeq,Beq]= deal([]);

k=@(y) -1*N.*y./M;

[x,a,b,c]=fminimax(k,x0,a,b,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub,@cons1);

g=min(x.*N./M)
```

The `cons1` function is

```
function [c,ceq]=cons1(x)

ceq=sum(x)-1;

c=[];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to restate the problem to ensure I've completely understood your question. It's not clear to me from the question if this is exactly what you
have in mind but here goes...

---

## Problem Statement

Maximize `min_i f(x,i)` over `x` subject to `0 <= x(i) <= 1` for all `i` and `sum(x) == 1`.

With `f` defined as

```
f(x,1) = k(1) * x(1)
f(x,2) = k(2) * x(2)
...
f(x,20) = k(20) * x(20)
```

and `k` as

```
k(i) = N(i) / M(i)
```

---

## Closed Form Solution

First, note that this is a convex optimization problem which means that any local maxima is also a global maxima. That means you're definitely not getting stuck in a local maxima. You can actually solve this by hand assuming that `k(i) > 0` for all `i`. I won't work the math here but intuitively we see that the functions are independent. Considering the constraints as well this leads to the conclusion that the optimal solution must satisfy `k(1)*x(1) == k(2)*x(2) == ... == k(20)*x(20)`. Due to the constraints this means the optimal point is

```
x = (1./k) / sum(1./k)
```

---

## `fminimax` Solution

The solve using `fminimax` it's better to avoid non-linear constraints if possible so that the solver can optimize properly. The equality constraint `sum(x) == 1` can be written as `A*x == 1` where `A` is a row vector of all ones.

Also, the upper bound `x(i) <= 1` is implied by `x(i) >= 0` and `sum(x) == 1`. Clearly if the latter two are satisfied then the upper bound is automatically satisfied. Since the upper bound is redundant we can omit it to speed things up a bit.

That said, the main problem with the code you posted is that the solver terminates early. This appears to be happening because the default tolerances are all on the order of `1e-6`, but the objective function takes values on the order of `1e-7`. What this means is that any step the solver takes ends up being smaller than the tolerance so the solver immediately stops once the constraints are satisfied.

You can avoid this by observing that `argmax_x(min_i(f(x,i)) == argmax_x(min_i(c*f(x,i)))` where `c` is some positive constant. For example if we scale the objective function by `1e7` then we begin operating in a more reasonable range but the optimal point `x` remains the same.

You've already negated the objective to convert the minimax to maximin so I won't say anything further on that.

Here's the corrected MATLAB code

```
M=[9.3 5.3 4.4 4.4 1.7 4.8 4.8 11 1.7 5.2 8.1 6.2 2.8 3.2 4 3.9 4.6 1 2.5 7.6]*10^7;
N=[2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2/3 0.5 2 2 2 0.4 0.5 2];

x0=zeros(20,1);

k = (N./M).';
scale = 1/min(abs(k));          % scale to put everything in a reasonable range
f = @(x) (-1*(scale*k).*x).';   % -1 to convert minmax to maxmin

lb=zeros(20,1);     % x >= 0
Aeq = ones(1,20); beq = 1;  % sum(x) == 1 constraint

[x,fval]=fminimax(f,x0,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb);
g = min(k.*x)
```

Alternatively, you should be able to adjust the solver options to avoid early termination. I tried briefly to find the proper settings but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I get what you are saying and made the changes but it still just does a couple of iterations and stops with the message 'local minimum possible. Constraints satisfied' without arriving at the right solution. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also I can't just use the closed form solution as I will be using the minimax method for other similar but more complex problems